# Okta JWT Token Decoding Issue

Tags: aws-lambda, jwt, aws-api-gateway, serverless, okta

I'm implementing a custom authorizer for AWS API Gateway using Okta's `okta-jwt-verifier-golang`.

My serverless.yml looks like this...

```
functions:
  myfunc:
    handler: bin/myfunc
    events:
      - http:
          path: myfunc
          method: post
          authorizer: app-auth
          cors: true
  app-auth:
    handler: bin/auth/app
```

My authorizer looks like this...

```golang
# app-auth/main.go
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "myapi/utils"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func Handler(ctx context.Context, event events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequest) (events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse, error) {
    bearerToken := event.AuthorizationToken
    fmt.Println("Token:" + bearerToken)

    _, err := utils.VerifyAccessToken(bearerToken)

    fmt.Println("error:" + err.Error())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error not null")
        return events.APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse{}, errors.New("Unauthorized")
    }

    return utils.GeneratePolicy("user", "Allow", event.MethodArn), nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
```

```golang
# utils/okta.go
package utils

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    verifier "github.com/okta/okta-jwt-verifier-golang"
)


func VerifyAccessToken(bearerToken string) (*verifier.Jwt, error) {
    tv := map[string]string{}
    tv["aud"] = "api://default"
    tv["cid"] = os.Getenv("CLIENT_ID")
    jv := verifier.JwtVerifier{
        Issuer:           os.Getenv("ISSUER"),
        ClaimsToValidate: tv,
    }
    jv.SetLeeway(60) //seconds
    fmt.Println("")
    return jv.New().VerifyAccessToken(bearerToken)
}
```

When calling the `VerifyAccessToken` func from the okta verifier lib in the CloudWatch logs I can see it throwing the following error: `token is not valid: the tokens header does not appear to be a base64 encoded string`. In the lib this happens in [this step](https://github.com/okta/okta-jwt-verifier-golang/blob/develop/jwtverifier.go#L141) and [this step](https://github.com/okta/okta-jwt-verifier-golang/blob/develop/jwtverifier.go#L276).

I'm also using the okta React app starter and posting to my endpoint using the accessToken.

```
try {
      const urlParams = decode(window.location.search.substr(1));
      const user = await this.props.auth.getUser()
      /* global fetch */
      const payload = {
        ...urlParams,
        user_id: user.sub
      }
      const response = await fetch(config.resourceServer.messagesUrl + "/v1/myfunc", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        // credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${ await this.props.auth.getAccessToken() }`,
        },
      });
```

On the client, I get a proper 401 due to this error but, even though `cors: true` and my endpoint sets `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"`, I get the following client error.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://myhost.com/v1/myfunc' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I assume this problem, however, will be resolved when the decoding issue is fixed.

I tried to decode it myself and it actually doesn't seem to decode correctly so the token might not be encoded correctly? Maybe the client application is doing something wrong? I've checked it over and followed the docs carefully but can't seem to resolve this on my own.

Any tips?

Update 1:
Looks like the token is in 3 parts. Part 1 is the header which throws the decode error. The entire token is properly decoded using https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/ and so was the header portion independently. This could be an issue during this step on the library code:

```golang
parts := strings.Split(jwt, ".")
    header := parts[0]
    header = padHeader(header)
    headerDecoded, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(header)

    if err != nil {
        return false, fmt.Errorf("the tokens header does not appear to be a base64 encoded string")
    }
```

Update 2:
So, `base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString` creates the following error `illegal base64 data at input byte 88`. However, decoding on jsonwebtoken.io works fine. This seems to be a lib [issue](https://github.com/okta/okta-jwt-verifier-golang/issues/36).

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the `event.AuthorizationToken` from the authorization handler does not parse `Bearer` out and was messing with the decode.

```
bearerToken := event.AuthorizationToken
token := strings.Replace(bearerToken, "Bearer ", "", -1)

_, err := utils.VerifyAccessToken(token)
```